# Assign values to a numpy array for each row with specified columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix `foo` with `n` rows and `m` columns.  Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> foo = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2) # n=3 and m=2 in our example
>>> print(foo)
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

I have an array `bar` with `n` elements.  Example:

```
>>> bar = np.array([9, 8, 7])
```

I have a list `ind` of length `n` that contains column indices.  Example:

```
>>> ind = np.array([0, 0, 1], dtype='i')
```

I would like to use the column indices `ind` to assign the values of `bar` to the matrix `foo`.  I would like to do this per row.  Assume that the function that does this is called `assign_function`, my output would look as follows:

```
>>> assign_function(ind, bar, foo)
>>> print(foo)
array([[9, 1],
       [8, 3],
       [4, 7]])
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: `foo[np.arange(len(foo)), ind] = bar`?

Comment: To start with, the result you say to with to be getting is not corresponding to the variables defined, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `ind` takes care of the first axis, you just need the indexer for the zeroth axis. You can do this pretty simply with `np.arange`:

```
foo[np.arange(len(foo)), ind] = bar
foo

array([[9, 1],
       [8, 3],
       [4, 7]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) alongwith `masking` -

```
foo[ind[:,None] == range(foo.shape[1])] = bar
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
# Input array
In [118]: foo
Out[118]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

# Mask of places to be assigned
In [119]: ind[:,None] == range(foo.shape[1])
Out[119]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)

# Assign values off bar
In [120]: foo[ind[:,None] == range(foo.shape[1])] = bar

# Verify
In [121]: foo
Out[121]: 
array([[9, 1],
       [8, 3],
       [4, 7]])
```